# Is it possible to link the opportunity and project with a different constituent in NetSuite?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

i am not able to populate the system field "Prject" on opportunity record if the project and opportunity records have a different constituent

I have created the project from opportunity, but by some reason the opportunity has not been linked with the created project. I tried to connect them(populate the project field on opportunity) using a script but get the error: Invalid job reference key  for the entity . It seems that netsuite doesn't allow project to be linked with the opportunity with a different client. Is there a way to populate the program field "Project" on opportunity and link the record with each other without changing the constituent on the records?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a new Custom body or column field that would allow you to select any Project (regardless of which constituent/institution it is attached to).  From there make considerations for why you want the 2 linked, and note that NetSuite will not complete any automation based on this custom field.  You will have to make other modifications depending on business needs.